# Why is FBX model all black in Blender after importing?

Tags: modeling, texturing, rigging, color, .fbx

I'm learning Blender in order to animate, but I'm pretty new to all this.

I don't know what's happening with my character, it looks all black.

I'm kinda lost in my learning process, so, if you see some topic that I need to learn, please, feel free to tell me.

[image: FBX rigged file]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: Hi Duarte! Sorry I couldn't reply sooner, I was at a camp with no internet on vacation. Here's where I got the model from: https://rigmodels.com/model.php?view=Claire_Girl-3d-model__LXG1NDL0BZ814059Q0RW9HZXE&searchkeyword=claire%20redfield&manualsearch=1              and thank you for answering me!

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, (with imported models) the correct image textures are not connected to the shader node.  To fix that, just double-check the materiel in the "Shading" workspace.

Another problem I've encountered that causes the materiels to be black has a weird fix: you have to delete the image textures node in the shader, and then re-add it, (with the correct image) and plug everything back up.

Hopefully either of these are helpful to you!

Comment: Hi Aidan! Sorry I couldn't reply sooner, I will try to implement what you've suggested, thanks a lot! :D

Comment: Hey, no problem.  Hope it works!